# Could you help me to solve this simple join issue?i am new to sql so no idea what is wrong with this

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT LEVEL_A.VALUE,LEVEL_B.VALUE,LEVEL_C.VALUE,LEVEL_C.VALUE
  FROM CUSP_VALUE_LIST_HEADER H
  JOIN CUSP_VALUE_LIST_ITEM LEVEL_C
    ON H.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO = LEVEL_C.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO
  JOIN (SELECT I.VALUE, I.DESCRIPTION
          FROM CUSP_VALUE_LIST_HEADER H
          JOIN CUSP_VALUE_LIST_ITEM I
            ON H.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO = I.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO
         WHERE H.CAPTION = 'SERVER_ENTITY'
           AND LOWER(NVL(I.DESCRIPTION, ' ')) NOT LIKE '%disabled%') LEVEL_A
    ON LEVEL_A.VALUE = REGEXP_SUBSTR(LEVEL_C.VALUE, '[^#]+', 1, 1)
    
  JOIN (SELECT I.VALUE, I.DESCRIPTION
          FROM CUSP_VALUE_LIST_HEADER H
          JOIN CUSP_VALUE_LIST_ITEM I
            ON H.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO = I.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO
         WHERE H.CAPTION = 'PurchaseType'
           AND LOWER(NVL(I.DESCRIPTION, ' ')) NOT LIKE '%disabled%') LEVEL_B
    ON LEVEL_B.VALUE = REGEXP_SUBSTR(LEVEL_C.VALUE, '[^#]+', 1, 1) || '#' ||
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(LEVEL_C.VALUE, '[^#]+', 1, 2)
 WHERE H.CAPTION = 'PurchaseSubCategoryList'
   AND LOWER(NVL(LEVEL_C.DESCRIPTION, ' ')) NOT LIKE '%disabled%'

  JOIN (SELECT I.VALUE, I.DESCRIPTION
          FROM CUSP_VALUE_LIST_HEADER H
          JOIN CUSP_VALUE_LIST_ITEM I
            ON H.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO = I.VALUE_LIST_HEADER_NO
         WHERE H.CAPTION = 'PurchaseCategoryList'
        AND LOWER(NVL(I.DESCRIPTION, ' ')) NOT LIKE '%disabled%') LEVEL_D
    ON LEVEL_D.VALUE = REGEXP_SUBSTR(LEVEL_C.VALUE, '[^#]+', 1, 1) || '#' ||
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(LEVEL_C.VALUE, '[^#]+', 1, 2) || '#' ||  REGEXP_SUBSTR(LEVEL_C.VALUE, '[^#]+', 1, 3)
 WHERE H.CAPTION = 'PurchaseSubCategoryList'
   AND LOWER(NVL(LEVEL_C.DESCRIPTION, ' ')) NOT LIKE '%disabled%'
 ORDER BY LEVEL_C.VALUE ASC;
```

Comment: Recommend that you supply a more complete example here and explain what you hope for and what this query is actually doing. Perhaps setting up all the tables and showing the working example in something like https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know what's wrong with it, simply by looking at whole lot of code? We don't have your tables and can't run it, while you didn't explain *why* you think there's something wrong with it. Any error? If so, which one?

Comment: It seems some syntax error in current query, can you provide some table structures along with dummy output ? it will be easy for us to identify and optimize that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, where is the call of table "LEVEL_A" by some FROM command? This can be corrupting all code. When you input a name with dot and another one, it mean as 'tableName.columnName'. I hope help.